# javascript input validation - Unable to validate when all fields are empty

Tags: javascript, validation

As a new guy in javascript am trying to create a script which is supposed to validate a registration form. Simple things, if 1 field is empty, throw the appropriate message. I succesfully managed it following the tutorials on the internet, it works the way i want it, database doesn't get updated when 1 field is empty.

However there is a problem. When ALL fields are empty the script somehow fails to notice this and proceeds with the registration perfectly.

My script is the following:

```
function validateForm()
{
var a=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["fname"].value;
var b=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["lname"].value;
var c=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["email"].value;
var d=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["username"].value;
var e=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["password"].value;

if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b=="") && (c==null || c=="") && (d==null || d=="") && (e==null || e==""))
  {
  alert("All Field must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("Last name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (c==null || c=="")
  {
  alert("email adress must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (d==null || d=="")
  {
  alert("Username must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (e==null || e=="")
  {
  alert("Password must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

This is drilling through my brain and driving me crazy for hours.
When 1 field is completed and the rest are missing i get the appropriate message for the first missing field and all good, registration is prevented.

But when all are missing, it just doesn't happen, registration is succesfull and enters all blank fields on my database.

I can't understand, it's here, right?

```
if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b=="") && (c==null || c=="") && (d==null || d=="") && (e==null || e==""))
  {
  alert("All Field must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
```

If fname is empty AND lname is empty AND email is empty AND username is empty AND password is empty, alert and return false.
I don't understand, how can there be a problem in something so simple? What am i missing?

And even if this line didn't existed, shouldn't the script get caught in the remaining if's that have only 1 clause and give the false there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would `try` it like this. You shouldn't need to check them all at once...

```
function validateForm()
{
  var a=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["fname"].value;
  var b=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["lname"].value;
  var c=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["email"].value;
  var d=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["username"].value;
  var e=document.forms["Registration_Form"]["password"].value;

  try {
    if ((a === '') || (a === null)) {
      throw new Error('First name must be filled out');
    }

    if ((b === '') || (b === null)) {
      throw new Error('Last name must be filled out');
    }

    if ((c === '') || (c === null)) {
      throw new Error('email adress must be filled out');
    }

    if ((d === '') || (d === null)) {
      throw new Error('Username must be filled out');
    }

    if ((e === '') || (e === null)) {
      throw new Error('Password must be filled out');
    }

    return true;
  }
  catch (formError) {
    alert(formError.message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it works, thank you very much.

I guess something was getting messed up in the way i checked them all at once?